# ManyToManyField Relationships Between Multiple Models

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models that represent books and authors.  A single book can have multiple authors and an author could have written multiple books.  So I am using Django's `ManyToManyField` type to link the two models to each other.

I can add a `Book`, using the Django Admin perhaps, and create an `Author` in the process.  But when I view the `Author` I just created it's not linked to the `Book`.  I have to explicitly set the reverse relationship between the `Author` instance and the `Book` instance.

Is that just the way it is or could I be doing something different?

Models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):    
    book_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField('Author', blank=True)

class Author(models.Model):
    author_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    author_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need two `ManyToManyField` definitions because the model class without the `ManyToManyField` is related to the other through the reverse relationship. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships

If you defined the two model classes as:

```
class Book(models.Model):    
    book_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField('Author', blank=True)

class Author(models.Model):
    author_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    author_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
```

then for any `Author` instance `a`, `a.book_set.all()` consists of the books that the author wrote (or co-wrote).

Comment: Ahhh!  That's awesome.  Didn't know it worked that way.  Many thanks!